# Set image height same as width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a image that is being displayed mulitple times, the image is being taken and has random heights.

I have set it up so that the images are displayed using `37.5%` of the parent div.

This has worked fine till I started to get irregular heights for the divs cause the height was not given. I have tried to set the height to `37.5%` although that manages to get a completely different value in pixels as the width gets.

I am just wanting to make the images perfect boxes without setting a hard `pixel` value or any other type of value.

**Current CSS**

```
/* Doesn't work. */
width: 37.5%;

float: left;
margin-left: 6.25%;
margin-right: 6.25%;
margin-bottom: 6.25%;
```

**HTML Image Being Edited**

```
<img src="LINK" />
<!-- Gets edited using ^ CSS. -->
```

**Note:** jQuery is allowed.

Comment: First, post both html/css, second, when you say "prefect boxes", what does that mean when having irregular heights?

Comment: Perferct heights as in - Equal heights, `width = 100px; height = 100px;` - So that they match and make a `perfect square` in  better words. @LGSon

Comment: That will mean that some will be stretched, right ?

Comment: That's what I wanted to have avoided, some will be stretched and I want them to be the same size as each other @LGSon (Height and Width = Same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is 2 samples, where `parent2`'s children have `background-image: cover`, which will keep the image's ratio rather than stretch it, which first sample does.

```css
.parent,
.parent2 {
  width: 60%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.child {
  float: left;
  width: 37.5%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
  .parent2 .child {
    background-size: cover;
  }

.child:after {
  padding-top: 100%;  /* 1:1 ratio = perfect square */
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
.child.nr1 {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/400/animals);
}
.child.nr2 {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals);
}
.child.nr3 {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300/animals);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child nr1"></div>
  <div class="child nr2"></div>
  <div class="child nr3"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
  <div class="child nr1"></div>
  <div class="child nr2"></div>
  <div class="child nr3"></div>
</div>
```

When using the `img` one set the image source/path in the markup, this can be done using a `div` as well, it that is required, like this

```css
.parent,
.parent2 {
  width: 60%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.child {
  float: left;
  width: 37.5%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
  .parent2 .child {
    background-size: cover;
  }

.child:after {
  padding-top: 100%;  /* 1:1 ratio = perfect square */
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" style='background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/400/animals);'
></div>
  <div class="child" style='background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals);'
></div>
  <div class="child" style='background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300/animals);'
></div>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
  <div class="child" style='background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/400/animals);'
></div>
  <div class="child" style='background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals);'
></div>
  <div class="child" style='background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300/animals);'
></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just adding to my current code to see if it works :) Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: I tried adding it and it didn't work correctly, but I'm willing to give you correct cause I'm a nice guy xD I just ran it off some jQuery worked easy.

Comment: @Jek Thanks, can you show, or easily describe, in what way my solution didn't work as you wanted?

Comment: Well I realised I didn't show the HTML and stuff as well as I should have and I appologise for that :P I just did some jQuery so onchange of the window size it will set the height to the width I've set, simple :) @LGSon